Login system on a react django application not working as intended
So I have a react and django application, and I have setup a login page. I want to be able to login to the portal and keep a track of the logged in user so that I can display the appropriate content. The approach I used was to set the jwt token as a cookie and use that to retrieve the id of the logged in user. But when I try to retrieve the cookie using request.COOKIES, and printing it I get AnonymousUser. I have made sure on the browser console that the cookie is being set on both the react server as well as the django server
Here is the model used to store the login details
class LoginDetails(AbstractUser):
    user_data = models.OneToOneField(UserData, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)  # Note: It's recommended to use hashed passwords in production

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


Here is the django view I am using for the login
class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')

        # Validate that both username and password are provided
        if not username or not password:
            return Response({'error': 'Username and password are required.'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        # Authenticate user
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is None:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid username or password.'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        # Generate JWT token
        token = jwt.encode({'user_id': user.id}, 'your_secret_key', algorithm='HS256')
        response_data = {'token': token, 'Role': user.user_data.role}
        response = Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        response.set_cookie('jwt', token, httponly=True)

        return response

The following view is where I am having trouble. I want to be able to display the details of the logged in user, and I am using the following view
class GetUserDetails(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        print(request.COOKIES)
        token = request.COOKIES.get('jwt')
        
    
        if token:
            try:
                # Decode the JWT token to extract user ID
                payload = jwt.decode(token, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
                user_id = payload.get('id')
                user = LoginDetails.objects.get(pk=user_id)

                user_data = user.user_data

                # Fetch and format user details
                education_data = list(Education.objects.filter(user=user_data).values())
                work_experience_data = list(WorkExperience.objects.filter(user=user_data).values())

                data = {
                    'user': {
                        'fullName': user_data.fullName,
                        'gender': user_data.gender,
                        'aadhaarNumber': user_data.aadhaarNumber,
                        'dateOfBirth': user_data.dateOfBirth,
                        'maritalStatus': user_data.maritalStatus,
                        'emergencyContactName': user_data.emergencyContactName,
                        'address': user_data.address,
                        'phoneNumber': user_data.phoneNumber,
                        'emailID': user_data.emailID,
                        'emergencyContactNumber': user_data.emergencyContactNumber,
                        'jobTitle': user_data.jobTitle,
                        'departmentName': user_data.departmentName,
                        'joiningDate': user_data.joiningDate,
                        'employmentType': user_data.employmentType,
                        'relevantSkills': user_data.relevantSkills,
                    },
                    'education': education_data,
                    'workExperience': work_experience_data
                }
                return JsonResponse(data)
            except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'Token expired'}, status=401)
            except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid token'}, status=401)
            except LoginDetails.DoesNotExist:
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'User not found'}, status=404)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'You are not logged in'}, status=401)

Now when this view is being called from the frontend, I get the following error
{'error': 'You are not logged in'}
I am not sure if I missed anything. I have made sure my settings.py has djnago-cors-heards in the installed apps, added in the middleware as well and even added CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST as well as set CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

are you able to print token from your print line?

Can you see if the token is send by printing? Also if Django and React have different origin cookies won't be send with request. If they have different origin how are you sending the cookie?

Please share a [mre], how does your frontend login and then make this subsequent request? Are you sure the cookies are being sent along in the request?

@shivankgtm When printing the token I get None

@DaksheshJain No it is not printing. I thought we could send the cookies even if they have different origins. What do I do so that both the react and django have the same origin?

@Revanth, what should you do is send the token in response and from client side(react) you should set it up in local storage using localStorage.setItem('jwt', token); or equivalent to it.

Ok after setting it up in the local storage, how do I access it in my django views?

No @Revanth, you should avoid using local-storage as they are not safe for authentication. You can use cookies but with relaxed rules i.e. SameSite=lax. You can then get token and add it in the header. If you still have issues understanding, I can create a answer.

Could you please create an answer, that would clear up a few issues for me. Thanks!

Hey @Revanth, did you check the answer?

You have different origin for both React and Django, which is why cookies isn't shared in the request. I still recommend you storing token in cookies as they are safe, you can manual add them to the request header.
This is how you will set the cookies. I am using a library called js-cookie.
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
Cookies.set(cookieName, token, { expires });

When sending request to the API, you will add this token in the header:
const header = {
   Authentication: `Bearer ${Cookie.get(cookieName)}`,
   // rest of the headers
};

fetch(url, header, ...yourRestOfTheStuff);

Now in Django, instead of getting token from cookie you will get it from header:
request.headers.get('Authentication') 
# you might have to parse it like removing Bearer from the string.

Your rest of the login logic seems to be in-place. If you are open to suggestions I would highly recommend you to use some libraries instead of implementing token authentication from scratch. Here are what some of the packages DRF recommends: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#third-party-packages
